# Thunderbird 91 GnuPG configuration for encryption - without plugin Enigmail

Tags: email, thunderbird, arch-linux, gnupg

Since version 78.1 of Thunderbird no longer works the plugin *Enigmail*.

Now I use version 91 under Arch Linux and Manjaro Linux, together with a Yubico YubiKey 5 NFC. GnuPG setup is done and the ECC keys are on the smartcard.

Thunderbird has been configured like this:

- mail.identity.id1.openpgp_key_id

  [The last 16 characters from the master key ID].
- mail.openpgp.allow_external_gnupg

  [true].
- My public key has been imported into Thunderbird, and has been accepted there.

The error message in Thunderbird is

> The secret key that is required to decrypt this message is not
> available.

Which sources were used?

- https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/openpgp-thunderbird-howto-and-faq
- https://wiki.mozilla.org/Thunderbird:OpenPGP:Smartcards
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/YubiKey
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GnuPG

Obviously I did something wrong in the last days.
What configuration is missing to use encrypted messages and enter my PIN with Thunderbird 91?

Answer (score 2):

It's always kind of stupid to answer your own questions. But at least I have found a possible solution. - I'm sure other people know better.

In any case, it helps to read all parts of the documentation:
https://man.archlinux.org/man/gpg-agent.1

> You should always add the following lines to your .bashrc or whatever
> initialization file is used for all shell invocations:
>
> ```
> GPG_TTY=$(tty)
> export GPG_TTY
> ```
>
> It is important that this environment variable always reflects the
> output of the tty command. For W32 systems this option is not
> required.

> If you want to manually terminate the currently-running agent, you can
> safely do so with:
>
> ```
> gpgconf --kill gpg-agent
> ```

I also installed *Kmail* as a test. The error messages there are much more helpful than with Thunderbird.

### ~/.gnupg/scdaemon.conf

```
# https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GnuPG#Shared_access_with_pcscd
pcsc-shared
# from "gpg --card-status" property reader: 1050:0407:X:0
reader-port 1050:0407:X:0
```

### ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf

```
pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry-qt
```

Only with this setting `pinentry-program` is it possible for me to enter the smartcard PIN under Thunderbird.

### Thunderbird configuration

```
mail.identity.id1.openpgp_key_id    [The last 16 characters from the master key ID]
mail.openpgp.allow_external_gnupg   [true]
```

And do not forget to accept your own imported public key:

Thunderbird menue `Edit` > `Account Settings`: `End-To-End Encryption` press `OpenPGP Key Manager` to open new window.

#### Which packages have I installed under Arch Linux or Manjaro Linux?

```
 - pacman -S --needed thunderbird
 - pacman -S --needed gnupg gnupg-pkcs11-scd libusb-compat pcsclite ccid pinentry
 - pacman -S --needed yubikey-manager yubikey-manager-qt yubikey-personalization yubikey-personalization-gui yubico-c
 - pacman -S --needed kgpg kleopatra
```

(I am using the DE *KDE Plasma*.)